# vba positive lookahead is too greedy

Tags: regex, vba

I'm using Access VBA to parse a string with regex.  Here's my regex function:

```
Function regexSearch(pattern As String, source As String) As String

Dim re As RegExp
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim match As match


Set re = New RegExp
re.IgnoreCase = True

re.pattern = pattern
Set matches = re.Execute(source)


    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        regexSearch = matches(0).Value
    Else
        regexSearch = ""
    End If


End Function
```

When I test it with:

```
regexSearch("^.+(?=[ _-]+mp)", "153 - MP 13.61 to MP 17.65")
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
153
```

because the only characters between this and the first instance of 'MP' are the ones in the class specified in the lookahead.

but my actual return value is:

```
153 - MP 13.61 to
```

Why is it capturing up to the second 'MP'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `.+` is greedy by default. The `.+` gobbles up every character until it encounters a line break char, or the end-of-input. When that happens, it backtracks to the last `MP` (the second one in your case).

What you want is to match *ungreedy*. This can be done by placing a `?` after `.+`:

```
regexSearch("^.+?(?=[ _-]+MP)", "153 - MP 13.61 to MP 17.65")
```